# Qgsrasterlayer tiles vanishing : Pyqgis : Request Max Try Error

Tags: pyqgis

```
url= 'type=xyz&url=https://mapserver.sensehawk.com/NjMAPJJBAD/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=22&zmin=1'

rtile = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'ortho', 'wms')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rtile)
```

Using the code above to load ortho tiles in QGIS, the tiles are vanishing from the QGIS map canvas after a fraction of a second and throwing the following **error: "Tile request max retry error. Failed 3 requests for tile 2 of tileRequest 2 (url: https://mapserver.sensehawk.com/JoExV6q8iM/17/22522/51943.png)"**. Attached are a few screenshots for reference.

[image]
[image]

Note: This code is being used in a QGIS plugin and is working fine on Linux OS, but is throwing the error on Windows

stacks: QGIS 3.28.7, Python 3.9.5

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to contain the error messages as text in the body of the Question. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same/similar error.

Comment: Can you share one working tile URL from your Linux system? You can use the Development Panel by pressing F12 and recording network requests.

Comment: @Vince noted ur suggestion will make changes accordingly, thank you

Comment: @bugmenot123 
Valid single tile URL from the same wms: https://mapserver.sensehawk.com/NjMAPJJBAD/20/742814/463629.png